# Solving the Datetime Mystery in SQL Server

Tags: sql, datetime

I'm new to this, and will appreciate if you can help me to understand how can I solve my issue with `datetime` format in SQL Server.

I'm trying to find some unique orders count on specific date:

```
select count(distinct(ID))
from dbo.Orders 
where CompletdDate like '2019-05-10%'
```

But an error occurred:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 53
>   Invalid column name 'CompletdDate'.

Maybe someone will know how to solve this? Some people say that I should you declare statement, but I have no clue, how and for what?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does CompletdDate exist as a column in the Orders table? Sure it's not a typo and you mean CompletedDate ?

Comment: Yes, Chris, the column is exist and data in it has the following format 2015-12-10 11:50:05.263, thanks for reply

Comment: Please read it carefully -- is the table also missing the final "e".  The error message clearly says there is no column named `CompletdDate`

Comment: It is a typo as @Chris said , and this can have many faces, please show the table definition (DDL)

Comment: Are you saying you have a misspelled column called `CompletdDate`. You database disagrees..

Comment: I pasted it wrong here,you are right, but anyway I'm trying to write the code suggested, and no results

Comment: Dears, sorry for misunderstanding, the column CompletedDate contains null results, so that was the reason I can't execute the code. Any options to skip the nulls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select count(distinct(ID)) from dbo.Orders where
TRY_CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CompletdDate, 105) = '10-05-2019'
```

If `CompletdDate` is null and you use convert or other cast function then you query will error. you should use `TRY_CONVERT` or `TRY_CAST` because this functions return null when column can't convert

Comment: you are right! And how can I escape the null in that case?

Answer (score 3):

If `CompletdDate` is actually a date column, then you should just check for equality:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID)
FROM dbo.Orders
WHERE CompletdDate = '2019-05-10';
```

If `CompletdDate` is datetime, and you want to restrict to just a given date, then you may try casting:

```
WHERE CONVERT(date, CompletdDate) = '2019-05-10';
```

Or maybe use a range:

```
WHERE CompletdDate >= '2019-05-10' AND CompletdDate < '2019-05-11';
```

Note: After seeing Gordon's answer, maybe `CompletdDate` should be `CompletedDate`.  But, that is just a typo, and not the major structural problem with your query.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple errors.  First, you should not be using string operations on dates.  SQL Server has good date functionality.

You have the name of the column wrong.  There is nothing I can do about that.  But the query should look more like this:

```
select count(distinct o.ID))
from dbo.Orders o
where convert(date, CompletedDate) = '2019-05-10'
---------------------------^ maybe the "e" was missing
```